# Pandas advanced column creation from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
df_detail = 
    car_brand   car_type
0   Toyota  Sedan
1   Toyota  Truck
2   Honda   Truck
3   Mazda   Sedan
4   Mazda   Convertible
```

I want to create a summary dataframe like below:

```
df_summary=
ID car_brand count_Sedan count_Truck count_Convertible
0 Toyota     1           1           0
1 Honda      0           1           0
2 Mazda      1           0           1
```

Is there a way i can create the count_ columns using pandas?
I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'car_brand':['Toyota','Toyota','Honda','Mazda','Mazda'],'car_type':['Sedan','Truck','Truck','Sedan','Convertible']}
df_detail = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_summary = pd.DataFrame({'car_brand':[]})
df_summary['car_brand'] = df_detail['car_brand'].unique()
df_summary['count_Sedan']=df_detail[((df_detail['car_brand']==df_summary['car_brand']) & 
                                     (df_detail['car_type']=='Sedan'))].count()
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

ANSWER:

```
df_detail.set_index('car_brand')['car_type'].str.get_dummies().sum(level=0).add_prefix('count_').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using `.str.get_dummies`:

```
df_detail.set_index('car_brand')['car_type'].str.get_dummies()\
         .sum(level=0).add_prefix('count_')
```

Output:

```
           count_Convertible  count_Sedan  count_Truck
car_brand                                             
Toyota                     0            1            1
Honda                      0            0            1
Mazda                      1            1            0
```

and add .reset_index to get index as integers:

```
df_detail.set_index('car_brand')['car_type'].str.get_dummies()\
         .sum(level=0).add_prefix('count_').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  car_brand  count_Convertible  count_Sedan  count_Truck
0    Toyota                  0            1            1
1     Honda                  0            0            1
2     Mazda                  1            1            0
```

Comment: thanks. is there a way i can have the index as integers and not car_brand?

Answer (score 0):

```
df_summary = (
    df_detail.groupby(['car_brand', 'car_type']).size()
    .unstack(fill_value=0)
    )
```